# Aplicar NumberFormat a arreglo de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, web

```
{
"00000124": {
    "2021": {
        "10": 17,
        "11": 12,
        "12": 8,
        "01": 20,
        "02": 14,
        "03": 20,
        "04": 14,
        "05": 16,
        "06": 11,
        "07": 18,
        "08": 15,
        "09": 9
    }
},
"00000611": {
    "2021": {
        "01": 23,
        "02": 10,
        "03": 25,
        "04": 18,
        "05": 2,
        "06": 2
    }
},
"00000189": {
    "2021": {
        "10": 58,
        "11": 59,
        "12": 58,
        "01": 76,
        "02": 54,
        "03": 65,
        "04": 82,
        "05": 27,
        "06": 23,
        "07": 49,
        "08": 54,
        "09": 41
    }
},
```

}

Intenté haciendo:

```
  let pesosAR = Intl.NumberFormat("es-AR", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "ARS",
    });
    
    let resultPesos = reducedDocsMontoVenta['00000189']['2021'].map(s => pesosAR.format(s))
```

Pero me devuelve error. Tambien intenté guardar el valor de reducedDocsMontoVenta['00000189']['2021'] y a eso hacerle un .map pero me sigue devolviendo error.  Alguna solución?

Muchas gracias!

Simplemente me devuelve "reducedDocsMontoVenta['00000189']['2021'].map is not a function"

Comment: Podríás añadir el mensaje de error que encuentras en vez del spam, por ejemplo :D Un dos tres cuatro cinco seis qué pereza el spam

Comment: La propiedad `['00000189']['2021']` no es un array (en general en lo que muestras no hay ningún array), es un objeto. También sería bueno que pusieras el error que obtienes, dices que te da y te sigue dando error, pero ¿cuál es el error?

Comment: Simplemente me devuelve "reducedDocsMontoVenta['00000189']['2021'].map is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Como es un objeto no es posible iterarlo con map es lo que te avisa el compilador
Utilizar metodos de la  API del lenguaje podes utilizar **entries(), forEach(), keys(), values()** y otros  para recorrer objetos.
Aunque se puede acceder con menos codigo lo codifique de esta forma para que puedas ver mejor como usar *Object.entries* para el aceso a las claves y valores
El método Object.entries() devuelve una matriz de pares propios de una propiedad enumerable [key, value] de un objeto dado ahi si podria aplicar map [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) la solucion con map esta al final--- Tene en cuenta de lo anterior ademas querias acceder a las claves en forma incorrecta
[formas de iterar un objeto](https://dev.to/duxtech/5-maneras-de-iterar-un-objeto-en-javascript-jkn)

```js
const reducedDocsMontoVenta ={
    "00000189": {
    "2021": {
        "10": 58,
        "11": 59,
        "12": 58,
        "01": 76,
        "02": 54,
        "03": 65,
        "04": 82,
        "05": 27,
        "06": 23,
        "07": 49,
        "08": 54,
        "09": 41
    }
}
}
const currency = function(number){
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('es-AR', 
    {style: 'currency',currency: 'ARS', minimumFractionDigits: 2}).
    format(number);
}
        
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(reducedDocsMontoVenta)){
  console.log(currency (value[2021][10]))
  //"$ 58,00" 
}
```

con lo anterior podes aplicar a cualquier objeto por ejemplo
se puede acceder con menos codigo opte por esta forma para que puedas ver mejor como usar Object.entries para el aceso a las claves y valores

```js
const reducedDocsMontoVenta ={
    "189": {
    "2021": {
        "10": 58,
        "11": 59,
        "12": 58,
        "01": 76,
        "02": 54,
        "03": 65,
        "04": 82,
        "05": 27,
        "06": 23,
        "07": 49,
        "08": 54,
        "09": 41
    }
}
}
 /* dar formato a 2021 por ejemplo
  node /tmp/cUtoYGlRDv.js
$ 58,00
$ 59,00
$ 58,00
$ 76,00
$ 54,00
$ 65,00
$ 82,00
$ 27,00
$ 23,00
$ 49,00
$ 54,00
$ 41,00

  
  */
const currency = function(number){
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('es-AR', 
    {style: 'currency',currency: 'ARS', minimumFractionDigits: 2}).
    format(number);
}
        

const res = {};
    Object.entries(reducedDocsMontoVenta).forEach(e => {
      const [key, value] = e;
      //console.log(key)
      res[key] = value[2021]
    });
//console.log(res[189])
  Object.entries(res[189]).forEach(e=>{
  const [key, value] = e;
  console.log(currency(value))
  
  }
  )
```

Por lo anterior podes usar tambien map el acceso a los valores  es de esta forma [codigo online](https://jsbin.com/gilaxur/edit?html,js,console)

```js
const reducedDocsMontoVenta ={
    "189": {
    "2021": {
        "10": 58,
        "11": 59,
        "12": 58,
        "01": 76,
        "02": 54,
        "03": 65,
        "04": 82,
        "05": 27,
        "06": 23,
        "07": 49,
        "08": 54,
        "09": 41
    }
}
}

const currency = function(number){
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('es-AR', 
    {style: 'currency',currency: 'ARS', minimumFractionDigits: 2}).
    format(number);
}
        


   const a=reducedDocsMontoVenta[189][2021]
console.log(a)
 const ars=Object.entries(a).map(([key,value]) =>currency(value));
console.log(...ars)
/*
[LOG]: {
  "10": 58,
  "11": 59,
  "12": 58,
  "01": 76,
  "02": 54,
  "03": 65,
  "04": 82,
  "05": 27,
  "06": 23,
  "07": 49,
  "08": 54,
  "09": 41
} 
[LOG]: "$ 58,00",  "$ 59,00",  "$ 58,00",  "$ 76,00",  "$ 54,00",  "$ 65,00",  "$ 82,00",  "$ 27,00",  "$ 23,00",  "$ 49,00",  "$ 54,00",  "$ 41,00" 


*/
```